# App requests successful, but no notification shown

Tags: facebook, apprequests, invite, facebook-app-requests, facebook-invite

I am using the normal setup for sending invites through the requests dialogue:

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'apprequests', 
    message: "Please add me, I am doing the same, thanks!"
  }, 
  function(response) {
   console.log(response);
  }
);
```

The response is successful, `response.to` shows multiple ids. So sending these invites works like it should. The problem is that these apprequests are not shown up as notifications like they usually do, instead the only place to find them [here](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests).

Has the API changed? Looking for [answers](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/532388000129311) has given me no results, though I did find this bug report from February 15th 2013.

Is Facebook just testing yet again, or has the API changed but not the documentation? I am truly grateful for any insights!

Comment: i have experimented the same fact today by using iOS sdk

Comment: @luca have you enabled the July 2013 breaking changes? I'm still looking for an answer to this but figured this might be one of the problems.

Comment: in my case i 'm developing an iOS app . I have just discovered on Stackoverflow that if i do not configure Canvas url notification do not arrive.. That was true , as i configured canvas url notification starts working

Comment: @luca so you're not using facebook authentication & publishing stuff for the user? That's what we're doing. We're a web app so we don't exactly need an app on facebook.com, but you're saying that's what you need? Do you think that's what we need as well?

Comment: yes sure i'm doing by using Facebook iOS SDK ...try this ,  go to your Facebook App, the Edit , then configure Canvas url both http and https , then retry notification... see this http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8204433/facebook-apprequests-not-working/8211249#8211249

Comment: I've just run into this with an iOS app...I assume others are also still seeing this..?

Comment: hi.. can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802803/facebook-app-invites-notification-not-working-in-ios. Please help me If you can.

Comment: @LucaRocchi I thought that Canvas URL was only regarding the Facebook Apps.Do we still need it if we have a native iOS or Android App.

Answer (score 19):

There's two simple things that might cause that problem.

One is that you application is missing the Canvas. Just add it from the your App panel in Facebook Developers.

The second one - make sure your app is NOT in SandBox Mode. If it is it won't send any notifications. I lost hours before figuring that out and changing the code in all possible ways.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this solve the no notification issue if your application is a Facebook application. But if it's just website that uses Facebook login, this solution doesn't fit.

Comment: I can confirm this. Setting canvas URL helps (turning off sandobox is needed only for production).

Comment: hi.. can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802803/facebook-app-invites-notification-not-working-in-ios. Please help me If you can.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but where do I find the canvas URL Settings ? Is it regarding only facebook apps.Mine is a mobile game but i still want to send app request over FB since i use FB login in the app.

Comment: According to FB Docs "Game requests are available for Games on Facebook and for mobile games on iOS and Android.".

Answer (score 11):

Its not facebook bug its a problem in your facebook app configuration :

Follow the below configuration and its working like a charm.

You just need to go in to the Facebook developer and select your app and goes in to the setting of your app and click "Add Platform" and select "App On Facebook" and than add canvas url in it. now try to send invitation and it will show the notification.

Thanks
Sagar

---

or go to [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/111/settings/),

Change 111 to your APP ID

-Fedmich

Comment: hi.. can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802803/facebook-app-invites-notification-not-working-in-ios. Please help me If you can.

Answer (score 3):

This was posted yesterday in facebook bugs [site](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/136643963196810). 
However, it is still not working for me even though I'm utilizing the exact code that the FB comment is referencing.

I realize this is not complete answer to the question and should be put in the comments. However I am a newbie and don't have enough reputation on StackOverflow to post comments. Emil, could you please let me know if you resolve this issue.

Comment: hi.. can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802803/facebook-app-invites-notification-not-working-in-ios. Please help me If you can.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, I added Secure Canvas URL, etc. But problem was I haven't provided iPhone Store ID inside iOS section in Settings.

Comment: If the GameRequests does not trigger Facebook notification unless you provide the AppStore ID of your iOS app, does this mean that v1 of your app cannot have the GameRequest receive notification function? Before you release v1 of your app, your AppStore ID cannot be validated by Facebook

Answer (score 0):

> As of Graph API 2.3, Game requests are only available to games.

As mentioned in Game Requests description, you have to create Facebook Web Games in App Portal, then you will get the notification with Game Request. Not for website anymore.

Comment: The docs say that it's possible to create Game Requests for Facebook or Mobile Apps. It doesn't have to be FB game.

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement facebook ‘apprequests’ instead of the deprecated ‘appinvites’ in an existing cordova app and spent hours debugging.

- ‘**apprequests**’ are only available in Facebook Apps categorized as ‘games’.
- You can send notifications **only to platforms (iOS, Android, Facebook web games) that are involved with the facebook app**. That means, you will never receive a notification in your browser if you miss ‘facebook web games’ as platform. My expectation was to be notified in the facebook browser app if I was invited from a Mobile app.
- iOS devices don’t get notifications.
  In my case, I’ve **missed to fill the app store id** in the Facebook app platform configuration. After that, notifications appeared instantly.
- If you like **notifications in the fb browser app**, you have to add ‘Facebook web games’ (formerly known as ‘canvas’) as plattform.
- You can save yourself a lot trouble by creating test users in the app role category of your facebook app.