# My Facebook App notifications only show on facebook.com, not in the iOS app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a mobile web app. I send notifications to users via facebook with the folowing api:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/

This works, the notification show up on facebook.com. But they are not showing up in the facebook app, which is what I want.

Comment: Where is the problem? For me it's the other way around. I'm working on a Unity3D mobile App. The notification show up on facebook app. But they are not showing up on facebook.com.

Comment: I guess when using the API on mobile, notifications only show on facebook mobile app and when developing on the facebook website, the notifications only show on the web. I've never found a solution to this problem..

Comment: This is very strange!

Comment: Here is the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792782/app-requests-successful-but-no-notification-shown