# Facebook Application Request not working on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to send an invite for the user's facebook friends to download our Android App.

I'm using the 3.5.0 FB SDK.

The way I'm using is this one:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();   
params.putString("title", "Title");
params.putString("message", "Test the thing");
params.putString("to", "FB USER ID");

WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),Session.getActiveSession(),params))
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            //Request cancelled or network error

                        }
                        else {
                            final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                            if (requestId != null) {                                    
                            }
                            else {
                                //Request cancelled, do nothing....
                            }
                        }
                    }

                })
                .build();
        requestsDialog.show();
```

I'm getting no error, and a valid Request Id when sending this to a FB friend of mine.
But the other user is not receiving absolutely nothing.

In some cases they might get a notification, but without my message or title.
Just that Lefteris did send you a request through the X app.

Any ideas why this is happening?
Is there a way to debug the request id to see what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20592090/312312)

It apparently only shows a notification to the other user, only if your App is marked as "App On Facebook".

Once I did the steps in this post, my notifications appeared to the users.

Comment: Where can I find the "App On Facebook" flag?

Answer (score 3):

If you are sending the request from your mobile application (ios or android), the app request notification is generally seen on your friend's mobile facebook app and not on the desktop.