# Unity Facebook apprequest works but no notification shown

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-app-requests, facebook-invite

How do I make my mobile game send a request that is shown as notification like in Candy Crush Saga game.

I went through this [App requests successful, but no notification shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792782/app-requests-successful-but-no-notification-shown) but can't find the solution. I don't know what to put in my canvas URL.

GAME is developed in Unity3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas apps means- the apps displayed inside facebook.com.

I think you are having the mobile app not a canvas app, so [Notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/), which is still in beta do not supports the notification in mobile. Acc to doc-

> Currently, only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications. Notifications are only surfaced on the desktop version of Facebook.com

So instead of notifications API, you can use different kind of [Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests)- whichever is more significant in your case.

Comment: :: so how does candy crush saga does it?

Comment: They are probably using request dialog (like most of the apps doeas), that i've mentioned in the answer.

Comment: i am also using app request....  FB.AppRequest("I just smashed ", userFids,"",null,null,"Lets See Data","Friend Smash Challenge!",sendCallBack );

Answer (score 2):

Solved .....  Your mobile app must pe on facebook (i.e on facebook appcenter )  ..then only it will be shown as notification

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue .. there is something that need to be done on FB App settings->Basic, Add another platform "Facebook Canvas". This solved the issue