# How to test Facebook App Invite on iOS without app on App Store

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native

I am currently developing an iOS app which is integrated with Facebook SDK for inviting users to use the app. The iOS app is not on the apple store since it's under development (obviously). However, when I use a test user to invite Facebook friends, no-one of his test friends receive a Facebook notification about it.

This is what I've done on Facebook:
I have created an test app and created an app link with [Facebook's tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api). I created test users for my test app.

This is the workflow with my iOS app:
I have a Facebook login button in my app. When a user logs in, there's a button to invite friends.  When user clicks on it, it opens the Facebook invite dialog. User can select friends and invite them. Everything seems to work on that end (no errors whatsoever).

Anybody has an idea of what's wrong with my setup?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

Fill out your Facebook Application Settings with the App ID of an already existing app, it doesn't have to be yours.

The only requirement is that it is live on the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you're talking about the App ID, are you talking about the iPhone Store ID that I have to set on Facebook? I created an App on Facebook that has its own App ID. When I go to the developer's app page on Facebook and select "Settings", in the "Basic" tab I can set an "iPhone Store ID". Is this what you mean?

Comment: Jeremie, yes, you're correct, the iPhone Store id you have set on Facebook!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was by creating a dummy Facebook Canvas App for my Facebook app. I would then get notifications when I share the 'private' app, as mentioned here: [App requests successful, but no notification shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792782/app-requests-successful-but-no-notification-shown/16901342#16901342)